# Finding the term independent of $x$ in $\left(e^x+e^{-x}+\ln e^{x+2}\right)^{20}$.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Find the term independent of $x$ in $\left(e^x+e^{-x}+\ln e^{x+2}\right)^{20}$.

**Method$1$:** The expression is $\left(e^x+e^{-x}+x+2\right)^{20}=\left(\left(e^{\frac x2}+e^{-\frac x2}\right)^2+x\right)^{20}$

Term independent of $x$ is the term independent of $x$ in $^{20}C_0\left(e^{\frac x2}+e^{-\frac x2}\right)^{40}$ i.e. $^{40}C_{20}$, which is the correct answer.

**Method$2$:** Using series expansion for $e^x$

$$\left(2(1+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+...)+x+2\right)^{20}=\left(4+2\left(\frac x2+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...\right)\right)^{20}$$

Here, the term independent of $x$ is $^{20}C_04^{20}=2^{40}$, which is not correct.

What's wrong in Method $2$?

Comment: You mean independent of $x$ in a sense that it does not involve a monomial of $x$? $e^{\pm k x/2}$ still depends on $x$.

Comment: What's the term independent of $x$ in $e^x+1$? Taylor series is unrelated to this problem.

Comment: I am afraid it all hangs on the meaning "what is the term". This problem should've been given in polynomial ring $\mathbb R[x,y]\left[\frac{1}{y}\right]$ - "find the constant term in $\left(y+\frac{1}{y}+x+2\right)^{20}$" and it will all be clear. $e^x$ (labelled "$y$" in the previous) is apparently not *meant* to be broken into anything else.

Comment: The second answer is correct (although its working has a typo). Your argument in the first method is wonky.

Comment: @ryang The OP in the first argument is treating $e^x$ as another independent variable - and this *seems* to be the "right" answer, i.e. "what the teacher wants to see". If the first solution is to be right, then this problem should be interpreted in the algebraic sense as noted above in my comment above. However, as there is *nothing* in the problem statement to suggest that *that* is how it should be interpreted, I claim that the problem is ambiguous, ill-posed and no wonder there will be dispute about what's the right solution. (A different interpretation leads to the second solution.)

Comment: As noticed, the question is not well defined, also without looking at Taylor series. I give my point of view (more elementary).

Take $f(x)=x+1$. What is the term independent of $x$? It should be $1$ right? But if we write $f(x)=2+g(x)$ with $g(x)=x-1$ than it should be $2$. In practice, we should define what a 'term' is to have a unique decomposition of $f$  into sum of functions (in the case of Taylor series, an infinite sum) from which we can extract a definite answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is ambiguous. There is no unique interpretation of what it means "term independent of $x$" because there is no unique interpretation of what "term" means there.

**Interpretation 1**: The *functions* $x^me^{nx}$ are all linearly independent in $\mathbb R^\mathbb R$, for $m\in\mathbb N_0, n\in\mathbb Z$, which is not *terribly* hard to prove (I will not do it here), and so:

$$(e^x+e^{-x}+\ln e^{x+2})^{20}= (e^x+e^{-x}+x+2)^{20}$$

as a real function in a real variable can be written as a *finite linear combination* of those $x^me^{nx}$. The question is: what is the coefficient multiplying the constant function $1=x^0e^{0\times x}$ in that linear combination? The answer will be $40\choose 20$, i.e. the first solution is right.

**Interpretation 2**: The functions $x^me^{nx}$ are all analytic in any neighbourhood of $0$ and so are all their linear combinations. The question is: what is the constant term in the Taylor expansion of $(e^x+e^{-x}+\ln e^{x+2})^{20}$ around $x=0$? The answer is $(e^0+e^{-0}+0+2)^{20}=4^{20}$, i.e. the second solution is right.

**Conclusion**: The answers end up different because they are answers to two different questions. Each answer is correct to *its own* question. The problem is that, from the wording of the question it's not easy to see how it "should" be interpreted. In my view, both interpretations could be valid, and so the question would need to be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a late reply, but in the Method 1 described, why have you assumed that the term independent will only be the 20th term of the expansion?

> Term independent of 
> is the term independent of 
> in $^{20}C_0\left(^\frac{}{2}+^\frac{{−}}{2}\right)^{40}
>  i.e. ^{40}C_{20}$

This is where the problem is lying. The question essentially is asking you the constant term of $\left(^+^{−}+ln(^{+2})\right)^{20}$ when it is expanded in terms of powers of x (And not powers of $e^x$). I see this problem incorrectly tackled using Method 1 in so many platforms and websites online, hence thought to come and clarify.

When you look at the expansion of $\left(^\frac{}{2}+^\frac{−}{2}\right)^{40}$, it expands as

$$\sum_{i=0}^{40} {^{40}C_{i}} \left(^\frac{}{2}\right)^i*\left(^\frac{-}{2}\right)^{40-i}$$

$$ = \sum_{i=0}^{40} {^{40}C_{i}} \left(1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2}}{2!}+\frac{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{3}}{3!}+.....\right)^i \cdot \left(1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\left(\frac{-x}{2}\right)^{2}}{2!}+\frac{\left(\frac{-x}{2}\right)^{3}}{3!}+.....\right)^{40-i}$$

In this summation, all the 40 terms are going to have a constant term $\mathbf{{^{40}C_{i}} \cdot 1}$ as you can see.

Therefore, the term independent of x in $\left(^\frac{}{2}+^\frac{−}{2}\right)^{40}$ is simply
$$\sum_{i=0}^{40} {^{40}C_{i}} = \ 2^{40} \ \ \text{and not} \ \ \ ^{40}C_{20}$$ (We have to consider the constant in other terms as well which is often ignored)

Further then solving, you get $4^{20}$ as also obtained in the Method 2. Whenever you are asked to calculate the term independent of x in a function which is continuous and differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$, I prefer to simply substitute x=0 (Or more generally, if you want to find coefficient of $x^n$, then find $\frac{f^n(0)}{n!}$)

I think the question is absolutely **not ambiguous** because whenever you are asked to find the term independent of x, it is implied whatever function is provided, it has to be expanded as a finite or infinite series of x itself (also called as Taylor series), in which case, the method 1 is ignoring many constant terms which are developed as part of expansion of $\left(^\frac{}{2}+^\frac{−}{2}\right)^{40}$